# Function for checking up two lists against each other?

Tags: asp.net, list

I have to List's.

```
List<User>
```

and

```
List<Friends>
```

In User are 10 Coloumns, one of them is "UserID", in Friends we havbe 4 Coloumns, one of them is "UserIDActive".

Now i Wanna have a new List in which only all Users are in it, which are also in Friends. Connected through the Coloum UserID == UserIDActive with have the same value.

How to do that?
With .contain I can only check two Lists with the same objects in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a simple join:

```
var matchingUsers = users
    .Join(friends, u => u.UserID, f => f.UserIDActive, (u, f) => u);
```

This overload of `Join` takes four arguments:

1. collection to join with
2. key of original collection to join on
3. key of joining collection to join on
4. result selector

If you want, you can return an anonymous type containing the user and the friend like so:

```
var matches = users
    .Join(friends, u => u.UserID, f => f.UserIDActive, (u, f) => new
    {
        User = u,
        Friend = f
    });
```

If there's a possibility that you have duplicates, be sure to use `Distinct`

```
var matchingUsers = users
    .Join(friends, u => u.UserID, f => f.UserIDActive, (u, f) => u)
    .Distinct;
```

Answer (score 1):

`List<User> newUserList = Users.Where(user => Friends.Select(friend => friend.UserIDActive).Contains(user.UserID));`